# Handling RestClientException and HttpClientErrorException

Tags: java, exception

I am handling few requests by making RESTFul call (Spring RestTemplate) to 3rd parties. In the code, I am trying to handle following condition .

```
     catch (final Exception ex) {
  if (ex instanceof HttpClientErrorException) {
      HttpClientErrorException hcee = (HttpClientErrorException)ex;
      if(hcee.getStatusCode() == NOT_FOUND) {
          throw new MyRecordNotFoundException(hcee);
      }
  }else {
      handleRestClientException(ex, Constants.MYAPP);
  }
```

Here is handleRestClientException implementation

```
    protected Exception handleRestClientException(Exception ex, String serviceName) throws Exception{
  if (ex instanceof RestClientResponseException) {
      RestClientResponseException rcre = (RestClientResponseException) ex;
      throw new RestClientResponseException(serviceName, rcre.getRawStatusCode(),
              rcre.getStatusText(), rcre.getResponseHeaders(), rcre.getResponseBodyAsByteArray(), null);
  } else {
      throw new Exception(serviceName, ex);
  }
```

But all org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(String url, Class responseType, Map urlVariables) throws RestClientException

Which is Parent of HttpClientErrorException

```
    java.lang.Object
      java.lang.Throwable
       java.lang.Exception
        java.lang.RuntimeException
         org.springframework.core.NestedRuntimeException
          org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException
           org.springframework.web.client.RestClientResponseException
            org.springframework.web.client.HttpStatusCodeException
             org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException
```

So, the if condition mentioned in my code never reaches as it is handled.

Could you please help me to handle the each exception in this hierarchy effectively?

Comment: IMHO, spring-web is stupid for turning basic status error handling into "invisible at dev time" runtime exceptions. Use a different library, like Apache's HttpClient. It is very easy to write a simple wrapper around it to turn it into a handy library that you can re-use in all your projects. Tie an object mapper into it and you're golden. Much better error handling that what spring-web provides.

Answer (score 5):

You should never do `if-else` in a catch block to handle different exceptions. The code is unreadable, probably slower in execution and in your example **any exception** (except for `HttpClientErrorException`) is handled like a `RestClientException`.

Handle them with proper catch blocks like this (more specific exceptions first, i.e. `HttpClientErrorException` before `RestClientException`:

```
catch (HttpClientErrorException hcee) {
    if (hcee.getStatusCode() == NOT_FOUND) {
        throw new MyRecordNotFoundException(hcee);
    }
}
catch (final RestClientException rce) {
    handleRestClientException(rce, Constants.MYAPP);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I understand. But different APIs are throwing different exceptions. I also need to have the MYAPP information in Exceptions so that I can come to know that which API has thrown which Exception and more error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to many others.

HttpClientErrorException is a subclass of HttpStatusCodeException which is a subclass of RestClientResponseException.

Proper handling includes handling of RestClientResponseException and ResourceAccessException

RestClientException has these two direct subclasses.

RestClientResponseException is thrown when the call is successful but there is invalid response like 500, 400.

RestClientException is thrown when API being called is down or not reachable because of TLS/Proxy.

```
try {
        
    responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url,
            HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,
            <ResponseType.class>);
} catch (RestClientResponseException rcre) {
    
    log4jlogs.error(
            "Business exception while calling the API! Error message: {}, Response Body: {} ",
            rcre.getMessage(), rcre.getResponseBodyAsString(), rcre);
    throw rcre;  // else throw custom business exception
} catch (ResourceAccessException rac) {
    log4jlogs.error(
            "System Exception. API not found, Error message: {}, rac.getMessage()",
            rac);
    throw rac; // else throw custom system exception
}
```